# Cannot save text from Edittext

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I have tried for hours now and I feel like giving up. Been to so many tutorials and online sites to try and fix this. I am trying to store text from an Edittext field to a variable but I have not had any luck. Here is my xml and java code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/uc_logo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/uc_logo"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/email_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passTxt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailTxt"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//variables
/*String login_test_name = "t";
String login_test_pass = "t";
EditText username , pass;*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //Remove action bar from screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //get EditText field data by id name
    /*username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passTxt);*/

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//code to change activity with BTN click (to register user)
public void registerUser(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserRegister.class );
    startActivity(i);
}

// code to change activity (to order menu if username and pass are ture)
public void orderMenu(View v)
{
    //variables
    String login_test_name = "t";
    String login_test_pass = "t";
    EditText username , pass;
    //get EditText field data by id name
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passTxt);
    String u = username.getText().toString(); // change EditText type to String type
    String p = pass.getText().toString();

    if (!u.equals(login_test_name) && !p.equals(login_test_pass))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "wrong username or password",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, u, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, login_test_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, login_test_pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderMenu.class );
         * startActivity(i);
         */
        Toast.makeText(this, "logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}//end order menu method
```

Comment: From where did you calling the orderMenu() method

Comment: ops sorry I have it in my xml ....     <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBTN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passTxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/loginBTN" 
        android:onClick="orderMenu" />

Comment: What is the value of u and p getting from edittext?

Comment: I type a "t" in both to test it. it goes to the if part every time and tells me i have the wrong pass or username. and when i use toast to see what i have in my variables from the edit text field they are empty

Answer (score 0):

`orderMenu(View)` appears to be set up as an on click callback. If this is intentional, you should add a button to your XML and give it the attribute `android:onClick="orderMenu"`

Also, unrelated, keep in mind that you are displaying several `Toast` messages in rapid succession. This will not look as good as you would hope, even if it is only for testing purposes. I recommend building a single message string, and then display it all at once.

```
if (!u.equals(login_test_name) && !p.equals(login_test_pass))
{
    StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
    errorMessage.append("wrong username or password\n");
    errorMessage.append(u + "\n");
    errorMessage.append(p + "\n");
    errorMessage.append(login_test_name + "\n");
    errorMessage.append(login_test_pass + "\n");

    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You don't have to use `StringBuilder`, you can make your string however you want. `StringBuilder` is just my option of choice for that.

Edit: From your comment on the question, I see that you do have a button using the `android:onClick` property. In the top of your layout you will need to add the attributes `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` and `tools:context="< package >.ClassName"`. In this instance, the package does not need to be the fully qualified package name. It can be a relative pathname, based on the package name set in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I have a button with the onClick attribute in my xml... `<Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBTN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passTxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/loginBTN" 
        android:onClick="orderMenu" /> `                                I think this should work

Comment: @user2852603 Check my response again, I just finished editing it after I saw your comment on your question.

Comment: i have this in my xml `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="fill"
    tools:context="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >` and is it aproblem that im using fragment_main.xml?

Comment: The problem appears to be `$PlaceholderFragment`. Your `orderMenu` method is in the `MainActivity` class. Your context is telling it to look for `orderMenu` in the `PlaceholderFragment`. So, either `orderMenu` needs to be moved to `PlaceholderFragment` (if you are actually using the fragment, this is what I'd recommend), or the context needs to be changed to `com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.MainActivity`.

Comment: I tried to move it to fragment and now im getting an error ...findViewById ERROR cannot make static reference to non static method

Comment: This is because the `PlaceholderFragment` is declared as `static`, which it should be. `findViewById` is a instance method. Static methods, members, classes, etc, cannot make calls on instance methods. you're going to need to change `findViewById` to `getActivity().findViewById(...)`. `getActivity()` returns the activity that the fragment is currently attached to.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in the comment, android:onClick ="orderMenu" is used in both the EditText in xml for each of the clicks you are trying to get the values from two EditText views, It seems not good, Tyr this once.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/email_txt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/uc_logo"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/uc_logo"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/email_hint"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:textColorHint="#000000"
android:textStyle="italic" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/pass_txt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/email_txt"
android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/password_hint"
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:textColorHint="#000000"
android:textStyle="italic" />
```

code:

```
username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passTxt);
 String u = username.getText().toString();  
String p = pass.getText().toString();
```

if you need to get the values when you click on it, try to add one button and add click listener for that 
   Example:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewByid(R.id.click_btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener{
 username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passTxt);
 String u = username.getText().toString();  
String p = pass.getText().toString();
 });
```

Comment: how is this any different?

Comment: Difference is, he is adding click listeners for edit text fields, and both the edit text fields have the same listeners.

Comment: I don't see that the OP is adding click listeners

Comment: That he explains in his comment.

Comment: i don't see that. the comments of the OP contain the xml for a button, which in fact contains an onClick attribute, but the EditText don't have this attribute, and your xml code does not seem any different from theirs.

Comment: Yep your right, i thought he added onclick listener to edittext field. But i tried with this code, and got worked

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the fragment_main.xml and thetext linking it in the .java file. This fixed my issues